# How to enable button for a single item in Flatlist in React native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a flatlist and it has edit and discard button which appear on clicking a button but I dont know how to enable buttons for single item only.Right now on clicking button to make appear edit/discard buttons is appeared for each item in list.

```
                  <FlatList
                    data={this.state.sizeData}
                    ItemSeparatorComponent={this.ItemSeparatorLine}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
                    renderItem={({item, index}) => (
                      <View>
                        <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                          <View
                            style={styles.card}>
                               <View
                                  style={{
                                  flexDirection: 'row',
                                  backgroundColor: '#f5f6fc',
                                  }}>
                      <Collapsible collapsed={this.state.editCollapse} style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>
                        <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                          onPress={() => this.editSizeData(item, index)}>
                          <View
                            style={styles.editButton}>
                            <Text
                              style={styles.text}>
                              Edit
                            </Text>
                          </View>
                        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                        <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                          onPress={() => this.deleteItemById(index)}>
                          <View
                            style={styles.discardButton}>
                            <Text
                              style={styles.text}>
                              Discard
                            </Text>
                          </View>
                        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                        </Collapsible>
                      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                        onPress={() =>
                          this.setState({
                            editCollapse: !this.state.editCollapse,
                          })
                        }>
                        <View
                          style={styles.button}>
                          <Image
                            style={styles.image}
                            source={require('../assets/interface_2.png')}
                          />
                        </View>
                      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                    </View>
                      </View>
                    )}
                  />
```

[image]

Comment: u need to compare the id of item with clicked item and render the button.

Comment: how can i do that? @Sodhisaab

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the **Edit button** from **this.props.children**

Second add it inside the **renderItem** prop with a condition,

that should only appear in case match the condition

e.g index === 0 (so, it will only render in the first item)

**example code**

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.sizeData}
    ItemSeparatorComponent={this.ItemSeparatorLine}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
        <View>
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                <View style={styles.card}>
                    <View
                        style={{
                            flexDirection: 'row',
                            backgroundColor: '#f5f6fc'
                        }}
                    >
                        <Collapsible collapsed={this.state.editCollapse === item.id} style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                            {this.state.editCollapse === item.id && (
                                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.editSizeData(item, index)}>
                                    <View style={styles.editButton}>
                                        <Text style={styles.text}>Edit</Text>
                                    </View>
                                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                            )}
                            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.deleteItemById(index)}>
                                <View style={styles.discardButton}>
                                    <Text style={styles.text}>Discard</Text>
                                </View>
                            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                        </Collapsible>
                        <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                            onPress={() =>
                                this.setState({
                                    editCollapse: item.id // change here the editCollapse to equal the item id
                                })}
                        >
                            <View style={styles.button}>
                                <Image style={styles.image} source={require('../assets/interface_2.png')} />
                            </View>
                        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        </View>
    )}
/>;
```

this code solution based on how you write the code,
i prefer another way which should render ItemComponent rather the **props.children**, it should gives you more control

Comment: I have changed the code part, please see and tell what can I do ? @Mustafa

Comment: example code updated ✅,

First, make sure when you click => set the editCollapse to the item id,

Second, only view edit if editCollapse === item.id

hopefully this works for you

Comment: editCollapse is a boolean variable, it would cause error as collapsed attribute take true or false only @mustafa

Comment: can you change it to take a string?

Comment: that cannot be possible as I am using Collapsible lib in which i have to either pass true or false, nothing other than that @mustafa

Comment: great, got it, which case you want to view edit button?,

code updated editCollapse now accept boolean value which is true or false